# Visual Studio Debugger Mysteriously Disabled? How do I get it back?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

This morning it seems that my Visual Studio debugger is disabled. When I press F5 or manually click on the "Debug > Start Debugging" menu item, the project builds and the browser opens up as expected (asp.net mvc) but the debugger doesn't start. What has happened to my IDE settings?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the environment completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a hunch. Is debug set to true in the web.config?

Comment: yea it is. i don't think anything has changed since it was last working. I'll probably try a devenv.exe /setup to restore settings.

Answer (score 3):

often this is the result of the ASPNET precompiler NOT realizing that your new binaries are new (and have breakpoints in them) so whats actually loading in the broweser is OLD code from before you set breakpoints (so of course you don't hit them).

If using IIS, recycle the app pool, do a CLEAN of the solution and then a REBUILD of the entire thing.  Also, manually purge the 'temporary aspnet compiled files' way down deep under %systemroot%\Microsoft.net\framework\blah\blah